# Is it smart to load dynamic (text+media) content via websocket?

Tags: ajax, navigation, websocket

Say I have a web page, and it has a websocket chat running on it. Now, my plan is, when the user clicks on any of the links of the page, the page is not refreshed. Instead, I send the request to the websocket (the same one on which the chat is running), and it returns the new page.

So, is this a good idea? Or should I go for Ajax?

Answer (score 1):

Ajax would be easier. You don't need branching inside the chat websocket listener this way, just request the needed page and put the response into the page body.